# Javascript: With an array of indices, splice a nested object using the indices to find the element with a recursive function

Tags: javascript, recursion, nested

Lets say I have an array: [0,1,5].

The object I want to splice is object[0].content[1].content[5].splice()

However, the array can be however long, if it's just length 1,

then object[0].splice()

If it's length 2, object[0].content[1].splice()

I want to create a recursive function that does this, so I don't have to make a lot of if length conditionals. Any ideas on how to do this? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Recursion is neither necessary nor desirable for solving a problem of this type. All you need is a simple loop:

```
var array = [0, 1, 5];

var result = object[array.shift()]; 
while(var index = array.shift()) {
    result = result.content[index];
}
var spliceResult = result.splice();
```

Comment: @DwightB An upvote and/or accepted answer would be appreciated if my answer solved your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

I get that recursiveness is not necessary in this situation. In the grand scheme neither is coding. But sometimes students like myself come to these places for help for specific questions based on constraints or edge cases. Try this one on for size. This specifically eliminates more than one occurrence of 0.

```
var takeOut = function(array) {
    if (array.length === 0) { return array };
    if(takeOut(array.slice(1))[0] === 0 && array[0] === 0) {
        return takeOut(array.slice(1));
    } else {
        return [array[0]].concat(takeOut(array.slice(1)));
    }
};
```